# binding model to multi-checkbox

Tags: angularjs

I have an edit form which is holding model data for a "project". The project has an array of users assigned to it, and the controller has another array of the entire user list available to be assigned. The form currently lists all availble users and what i want to do is tick the ones already assigned to the project and if the user modifies this list of checked/unchecked items, update the related project.users property.

Code is at : http://plnkr.co/edit/e2Rc45mgWDkgdHxz1bz0?p=preview

controller

```
angular.module('app',  [])

.controller('ProjectsController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.project = {"projectID":"26","projectName":"project one","projectDescription":"blah",
    "users":[{"userFullName":"Ian","userID":"2"},
    {"userFullName":"Kevin","userID":"33"},
    {"userFullName":"Peter","userID":"32"}]
    };

    $scope.collaborators = [
      {"userID":"2","userFullName":"Ian"},
      {"userID":"33","userFullName":"Kevin"},
      {"userID":"32","userFullName":"Peter"},
      {"userID":"31","userFullName":"Tom"}
      ];
    $scope.updateProject = function(project){
      console.log(project);
    }

  }]);
```

Form

```
 <form name="editProjectForm" novalidate ng-submit="updateProject(project)"  >
    <label>Name</label><BR>
    <input type="text" ng-model="project.projectName" class="form-control" required><BR><BR>
    <label>Description</label><BR>
    <textarea ng-model="project.projectDescription" class="form-control" required></textarea>
    <br>
    <label>Assigned to work on project</label><BR>
    <label ng-repeat="collaborator in collaborators">
        <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="???" /> {{collaborator.userFullName}} &nbsp;
    </label>
    <BR> <BR>
    <input type="submit" value="Update project details" class="btn btn-primary">

</form>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/e2Rc45mgWDkgdHxz1bz0?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Checklist-model](http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/). It adds `checklist-model` and `checklist-value` directives for lists of checkboxes which I think is exactly what you need.

Using it in your example could look something like this:

```
<label ng-repeat="collaborator in collaborators">
    <input type="checkbox"
           checklist-model="project.users"
           checklist-value="collaborator" /> {{collaborator.userFullName}} &nbsp;
</label>
```

It has an MIT license, so it shouldn't be an issue using it in a commercial project.

Answer (score 1):

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/h2xsswCFFelxjFvZL4NP?p=preview)

You could create a `$scope.checked` object within the controller which will scan your project users vs. collaborator users and form booleans based on that.

**JS**

```
// Checked model will not interfere with existing collaborators
// or project models. Simply a glue between controller and view.
$scope.checked = {};
// Add all possible collaborators to the checked model
angular.forEach( $scope.collaborators, function( item )
{
  $scope.checked[ item.userID ] = false;
});
// Auto-check any users already assigned to the project
angular.forEach( $scope.project.users, function( item )
{
  $scope.checked[ item.userID ] = true;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<label ng-repeat="collaborator in collaborators">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked[collaborator.userID]" /> {{collaborator.userFullName}} &nbsp;
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks, although I want to actually "interfere" with the project model and update project.users to contain an array of all checked items. Although I could loop through $scope.checked and rebuild project.users, is there a more "angular" way in regards to data binding?

Comment: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4cwlMmyCmrnb46YNY95F?p=preview). Yes, I would switch the format of `$scope.project.users` to a simple user ID array. Then on updating the `$scope.checked` model, adjust `$scope.projects.users`.